# Calculating walkable catchments from polygons

Tags: qgis, distance, network, catchment-area

I am working in QGIS, and I would like to calculate 400 m walking catchments from a set of parks (polygons).

At the moment I have:

- Parks Layer (polygon)
- Urban Grid layer, which shows publicly accescible space (polygon)

I have thought of converting the polygons to centroids and then using the Interface Catchment plugin, however some of the parks are very long/linear, so this would not be accurate in this case.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing the data

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to calculate walking catchments from the park borders? I think you have to:

1. Calculate densified set of polygon vertices. You can use algorithm  **qgis:densifygeometriesgivenainterval** with interval like 10 - 50 meters. Depends of accuracy you need.
2. Convert new polygons to point layer - **native:extractvertices**
3. Apply IC plugin to the point layer.
4. Cut linear layer with source polygons of parks - **native:difference** because you don't need inner parts of parks.
5. Delete duplicates from linear layer - **native:deleteduplicategeometries**

BTW I hope "Urban Grid layer" is polygon?